# How to link images from outside of the next js project folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm working on a project where I'm node.js and express for the back-end and next js for the front-end.

I have a form where users can create new products every product has an image.

I'm using multer for image uploads and saving the images inside the uploads folder.

In next js I'm using an image path like this:

```
/uploads/imag-name.png
```

But I'm getting could not load the image.

here's my folder structure

```
Website
--------
  client
  -------
    components
    pages
    public
    styles
    ...

  uploads
  -------
    image-name.png
    ...

  server
  ------
    config
    controllers
    middlewares
    models
    routes
    utils
    server.js
```

Comment: What file are you loading the image from?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to be stepping out  of `pages/client` and into `uploads so the path should look something like `../../uploads/imag-name.png`

Comment: Is your server running on a different `port` from your `nextjs` client

Comment: Yes `5050` for server and `3000` for next js

Comment: Consider moving the `uploads` directory into the `client` directory

Comment: moving the `uploads` directory to `/client/public/`

Comment: Yes, did you do that already?

Comment: Do you want to answer the question? so I can accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Move your `uploads` directory into your `client/public` director so the structure should look like this

```
Website
--------
  client
  -------
    components
    pages
    public
      uploads
         -------
         image-name.png
    styles
    ...
```

Comment: not sure how this is considered an answer to the question? The original question was how to reference images in a folder outside the project path and the answer was to move the images to inside the question. I wish I can get an answer to the original question because I am in the same situation.